# make consumer as coroutine and producer as main thread in lua

Tags: lua, consumer, producer

This is the consumer-producer , producer as coroutine and consumer as main thread:

```
function receive (prod)
   local status, value = coroutine.resume(prod)
   return value
end

 function send (x)
    coroutine.yield(x)
 end

 function producer ()
   return coroutine.create(function ()
       while true do
        local x = io.read()
        -- produce new value
        send(x)
       end
    end)
  end

  function filter (prod)
     return coroutine.create(function ()
        for line = 1, math.huge do
            local x = receive(prod)
            -- get new value
            x = string.format("%5d %s", line, x)
            send(x)
            -- send it to consumer
         end
      end)
   end

   function consumer (prod)
      while true do
        local x = receive(prod)
        io.write(x, "\n")
      end
   end

   -- get new value
   -- consume new value
   consumer(filter(producer()))
```

and here is my answer bt is not running as expected:

```
   function receive (x)
     coroutine.yield(x)
    end

   function send (cons, x)
     local status, value = coroutine.resume(cons, x)
     return value
   end

  function producer (cons)
   while true do
    local x = io.read()
    -- produce new value
    send(cons, x)
   end
 end

 function filter (cons)
   return coroutine.create(function (x)
     for line = 1, math.huge do
        local _, x = receive(x)
        -- get new value
        x = string.format("%5d %s", line, x)
        send(cons, x)
        -- send it to consumer
    end
    end)
  end

  function consumer ()
   return coroutine.create(function(x) 
      while true do
        local x = receive(x)
        io.write(x, "\n")
      end
    end)
 end

 -- get new value
 -- consume new value
   producer(filter(consumer()))
```

Thing is while getting into local x = receive(x) into filter() function, then it is going again to producer() waiting for new input wthout formating x input.
Any suggestion? I do not want to change the initial way was implemented, meaning the recieve() bound into the consumer() and send() bound into reciever().

Answer (score 0):

The receiver isn't returning anything, let's add a return.

```lua
function receive(x)
    return coroutine.yield(x)
end
```

The receiver only returns one value in your example, let's remove `_`.

```lua
local x = receive(x)
```

Then all your consumer, filter etc are one input delayed because you ignore the first x, and then enter the loop.